# How do I Import TypeLib as safecall vs stdcall in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, typelib

Delphi versions before 2010 had an option in the Delphi Environment that one could set: "All v-table interfaces".  This would change the calling convention when importing type libraries.  In 2010, the option is gone.  How do I import a type library with the safecall calling convention?  I'm hoping maybe there is a more granular level of control in 2010 than previous versions, but regardless - how do I do this now?

Thanks.

Comment: You may have found a bug in the new TLB importer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried using the "All v-table interfaces" option in the Delphi 2010 IDE. It was definitely broken in D2009.

You can use the command-line tlibimp tool to create the _tlb.pas files you need:

```
tlibimp -P -Pt <tlb file>
```

Comment: I noticed that the help info for tlibimp incorrectly states that the parameter to do this is -Pt-. It should be -Pt or -Pt+.

Comment: What the help info doesn't tell you is that it is showing you the default settings for each of the options. -Pt- in the help is saying the "Map all HRESULT to safecall" is off by default - I've been caught by this one as well :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the resulting .ridl file that is generated, you will see that the methods have _stdcall defined.

You have a finer level of control using the .ridl files now.

Comment: These type libraries are coming from *other* applications.  I do not have a .ridl file for them.  I am *importing* the library.  Thank-you for the attempt.